# How log commands executed by user

Tags: linux, bash, logging, audit

First at all, I have working some years with snoopy and it's not what I need, also checking history file isn't a solution for me.

I have to give ROOT access to a developer to install a program on the server and I know that he will remove history after he exits session.

I need to check what commands he ran to protect server from abuse activity.

Any solution to logging commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can log all the activity from the users with the `psacct` [package](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html).

- The `psacct` package contains several utilities for monitoring process
  activities, including `ac`, `lastcomm`, `accton` and `sa`.
- The `ac` command displays statistics about how long users have been logged on.
- The `lastcomm`command displays information about previous executed
  commands.
- The `accton` command turns process accounting on or off.
- The `sa` command summarizes information about previously executed
  commands.

Installation on RHEL/Fedora/CentOS

```
# yum install psacct
```

Installation on Ubuntu/Debian

```
$ sudo apt-get install acct
```

OR

```
# apt-get install acct
```

In RHEL type the following commands to create */va/account/pacct* file and start the service

```
# chkconfig psacct on

# /etc/init.d/psacct start
```

In Suse type the following commands to create */va/account/pacct* file and start the service

```
# chkconfig acct on

# /etc/init.d/acct start
```

Display commands executed by *USER*

```
$ lastcomm [USER]
```

Comment: This is barely useful. It will only log the main commands not arguments. i.e. `rm` will tell you nothing which file the user deletes.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to give ROOT access to a developer to install a program ...

No, you don't.
Get them to *write down* or, better yet, *script* the installation steps and execute them on their behalf.
This is called Separation of Duties.  They are a Developer.  You are a SysAdmin.  Let *them* do the stuff that *they're* good at (writing code, testing, etc.) and *you* do the stuff that *you're* good at (keeping machines secure and running efficiently, etc.).

> ... I know that he will remove history after exit session.

Is this "standard practice" for your organisation?
If not, why do they feel the need to do so?

> I need to check what commands he run to protect server from abuse activity.

It is clear that you do not *trust* this Developer.
If that is the case, then you should not let them *anywhere near* this server.
It's *your job* on the line if you allow them to install something questionable on there.

Escalate the issue to Management if necessary.